# how to extend a abstract class in java

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism, abstract-class, abstract

I have a made an engine class that is as follows. based on

Engine: Interface   that    extends Java’s  Comparable  (to compare among   engines)    and declares    an  integer 
getter  method  “getForce”, which   indicatesthat   engine subclasses will  have    a   force they  are capable of
producing.

```
public interface Engine extends Comparable<Engine>{

public int getForce();

}
```

I am trying to make an `AbstractEngine` class based on the following description.

`AbstractEngine`: Abstract class implemented by most engines.  It subclasses from Engine and has an integer field indicating its force.  This field is initialized through a constructor. The class overrides `getForce` from `Engine` and `compareTo` from `Comparable`. The comparison of two engines is done by finding the difference between their forces (in such a way that sorting a collection of engines arranges. I am confused on overriding the methods from `Engine` and making sure `AbstractEngine` has the compare to the `Engine` has.

This is what I have at the moment, but it's failing a JUnit test checking if `AbstractEngine` has the `getForce`, `equals`, and `CompareTo`. Is there a specific way I have to extend the methods?

```
abstract class AbstractEngine implements Engine {

public AbstractEngine(int force){

}
public int compareTo(Engine o) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}
}
```

here is the junit test

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Test;

public class EngineTest {

@Test
public void test0_EngineImplementsComparableAndDefinesGetForce() {
    Engine engine = new Engine() {
        @Override
        public int compareTo(Engine o) {
            return 0;
        }
        @Override
        public int getForce() {
            return 0;
        }
    };
    assertTrue( "Incorrect result", engine instanceof Comparable );
}
@Test
public void test1_AbstractEngineIsAnEngine() {
    Engine engine = new AbstractEngine( 2 ) { };
    assertTrue( "Incorrect result", engine instanceof Engine );
}
@Test
public void test2_AbstractEngineHasGetForce() {
    Engine engine   = new AbstractEngine( 24 ) { };
    int    actual   = engine.getForce();
    int    expected = 24;
    assertEquals( "Incorrect result", expected, actual );
}
@Test
public void test3_AbstractEngineHasEquals() {
    Engine  a, b;
    boolean actual;
    // equal to itself
    a      = new AbstractEngine( 42 ) { };
    actual = a.equals( a );
    assertTrue ( "Incorrect result", actual );
    // equal to another engine with the same force
    a      = new AbstractEngine( 19 ) { };
    b      = new AbstractEngine( 19 ) { };
    actual = a.equals( b );
    assertTrue ( "Incorrect result", actual );
    // not equal to another engine with a different force 
    a      = new AbstractEngine( 22 ) { };
    b      = new AbstractEngine( 24 ) { };
    actual = a.equals( b );
    assertFalse( "Incorrect result", actual );
    // not equal to null
    actual = a.equals( null );
    assertFalse( "Incorrect result", actual );
    // not equal to some other object
    actual = a.equals( "22" );
    assertFalse( "Incorrect result", actual );
    // not equal to some other object
    actual = a.equals(  22  );
    assertFalse( "Incorrect result", actual );
}
@Test
public void test3_AbstractEngineHasCompareTo() {
    Engine a, b;
    int    actual;
    // equal to itself
    a      = new AbstractEngine( 42 ) { };
    actual = a.compareTo( a );
    assertTrue( "Incorrect result", actual == 0 );
    // equal to another engine with the same force
    a      = new AbstractEngine( 9000 ) { };
    b      = new AbstractEngine( 9000 ) { };
    actual = a.compareTo( b );
    assertTrue( "Incorrect result", actual == 0 );
    // goes before a more powerful engine 
    a      = new AbstractEngine( 23 ) { };
    b      = new AbstractEngine( 24 ) { };
    actual = a.compareTo( b );
    assertTrue( "Incorrect result", actual < 0 );
    // goes after a less powerful engine 
    actual = b.compareTo( a );
    assertTrue( "Incorrect result", actual > 0 );
}
@Test
public void test4_OxIsAnEngine() {
    Ox ox = new Ox( 3 );
    assertTrue( "Incorrect result", ox instanceof AbstractEngine );
}
@Test
public void test5_OxHasGetForce() {
    Engine engine   = new Ox( 4 );
    int    actual   = engine.getForce();
    int    expected = 4;
    assertEquals( "Incorrect result", expected, actual );
}
@Test
public void test5_OxHasEquals() {
    Engine  a, b;
    boolean actual;
    // equal to itself
    a      = new Ox( 42 );
    actual = a.equals( a );
    assertTrue ( "Incorrect result", actual );
    // equal to another engine with the same force
    a      = new Ox( 19 );
    b      = new Ox( 19 );
    actual = a.equals( b );
    assertTrue ( "Incorrect result", actual );
    // not equal to another engine with a different force 
    a      = new Ox( 22 );
    b      = new Ox( 24 );
    actual = a.equals( b );
    assertFalse( "Incorrect result", actual );
    // not equal to another engine of equal force 
    a      = new Ox            ( 21 );
    b      = new AbstractEngine( 21 ) { };
    actual = a.equals( b );
    assertFalse( "Incorrect result", actual );
    // not equal to null
    actual = a.equals( null );
    assertFalse( "Incorrect result", actual );
    // not equal to some other object
    actual = a.equals( "blah" );
    assertFalse( "Incorrect result", actual );
    // not equal to some other object
    actual = a.equals(  111  );
    assertFalse( "Incorrect result", actual );
}
}
```

Comment: What does your Junit test look like? It probably fails because `compareTo` always returns 0 and you haven't actually set each `Engine`'s `force` field.

Comment: The entire class `AbstractEngine` is obsolete. It does not add anything useful to its base class. And there’s no real reason why it is abstract. And…

Comment: I really think you just need to use the `force`.

Comment: @Cruncher I'm dead on that one. _You_ used the force...

Comment: Unless you need `Engine` to be a concrete class, you could make it `abstract` too.

Comment: Engine has to be a interface that extends java's Comparable I think set it up correctly

Comment: This question needs to be deleted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In the constructor of `AbstractEngine`, you need to set the `force` member variable.
- It is not necessary to have a `getForce()` method in `AbstractClass`, if this method looks exactly the same as in class `Engine`.
- You have to implement the `compareTo` method as described in the assignment, either in the `Engine` class or in the `AbstractEngine` class.

Reading the description, shouldn't the `force` member variable be in the `AbstractEngine` class instead of the `Engine` class? (If you put it in `AbstractEngine`, then `getForce()` should also be in `AbstractEngine` instead of `Engine`).